sweetalert and form submit
I have a form and I want to trigger an alert (using sweetalert) on submit:
<form id="verbale" class="verbale" action="editor_conferma.php" method="post">
...
<input id="go" type="submit" name="go" value="go" class="swa-confirm">
</form>

<script>
$(document).on("submit", ".swa-confirm", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $myForm = $('.verbale');
                if (!$myForm[0].checkValidity()) {
                    $myForm[0].reportValidity()
                } else {
                    swal({
                        title: "Are you sure?",
                        text: "Did you check?",
                        type: "warning",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "Yes, Submit!",
                    }).then(function (result) {
                        $myForm.submit();
                    });
                }
            });
</script>

The sweetalert dialog appears but when I confirm, the form is not passed on and submit does not seem to work.
Any hints?

NEVER call anything submit in a form if you want to call .submit(). Rename ID and NAME

Also use the submit event instead of the click event on a submit button

I have. Now the form is passed on but the sweetalert dialog is not triggered anymore.

Please update the code with the new id and name attributes.

Initially you gave the submit button the ID/Name of submit - that will block the submission
You need to assign the submit to the FORM and NOT use the jQuery submit since it triggers the sweetalert again
sweetalert.js.org, has buttons
Lastly I test that Yes, Submit is clicked
Note: If you use required, there is no need to test the validity unless you have turned standard validation off and you want to handle the validation yourself


$("#verbale").on("submit", function(e) { // or if inserted $(document).on("submit","#verbale",function() {
  e.preventDefault();
  const myForm = this;
  if (!myForm.checkValidity()) { // this is not needed if you have required
    myForm.reportValidity()
  } else {
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "Did you check?",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: {
        cancel: true,
        confirm: "Yes, Submit!"
      }
    }).then(function(result) {
      if (result) myForm.submit(); // do not submit if cancelled
    })
  }
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<form id="verbale" class="verbale" action="editor_conferma.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" required />
  <input id="go" type="submit" name="go" value="go" class="swa-confirm">
</form>



SWAL2.11


$("#verbale").on("submit", function(e) { // or if inserted $(document).on("submit","#verbale",function() {
  e.preventDefault();
  const myForm = this;
  if (!myForm.checkValidity()) { // this is not needed if you have required
    myForm.reportValidity();
  } else {
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "Did you check?",
      icon: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, Submit!",
      cancelButtonText: "Cancel"
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        myForm.submit(); // submit if confirmed
      }
    });
  }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<form id="verbale" class="verbale" action="editor_conferma.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" required />
  <input id="go" type="submit" name="go" value="go" class="swa-confirm">
</form>




It works nicely with sweetalert (v.1): https://sweetalert.js.org/ (but I have encountered a problem using the latest repository v.2)

I have two versions: sweetalert.js.org and sweetalert2.github.io now

Thanks, I had not seen the newest update.

@mplungjan why check if the form is valid in the submit callback? If the form is not valid, the submit event will not happen.

@chrwahl You are correct - I do not assume OP's code is complete. Perhaps they turned off validation to do a manual one. But if not, then yes, the test is not necessary. I have added this to my answer

I know that this question has already been answered, and you would like to use jQuery and sweetalert, but I couldn't help it. Here is an example of a native dialog box and how it can be used in connection with the submit event.


const verbale_form = document.forms.verbale;
const verbale_dialog = document.getElementById('verbale_dialog');

verbale_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  verbale_dialog.showModal();
});

verbale_dialog.addEventListener('close', e => {
  if (e.target.returnValue == 'yes') verbale_form.submit();
});
dialog {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em 5em;
  color: DimGray;
}

dialog form {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: .5em;
}

dialog>div {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: .5em;
}

dialog button {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .2em;
  padding: 1em;
}

dialog button[name="yes"] {
  background-color: MediumSlateBlue;
}

dialog button[name="cancel"] {
  background-color: SlateGray;
}

dialog.warning:before {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  content: '!';
  color: PeachPuff;
  font-size: 4em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid thick PeachPuff;
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
<form id="verbale" class="verbale" action="editor_conferma.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" required>
  <button type="submit">go</button>
</form>
<dialog id="verbale_dialog" class="warning">
  <div>
    <h2>Are you sure?</h2>
    <p>Did you check?</p>
    <form method="dialog">
      <button name="yes" value="yes">Yes, Submit!</button>
      <button name="cancel" value="cancel" formmethod="dialog">Cancel</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</dialog>



